# hits.page.searchKeyword doesn't match search page url

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Still playing with the BigQuery google_analytics_sample data and demo shop website.

When I'm searching for a product on the google merchandise store the page search URL looks like this `/asearch.html vid=20160512512&key=cool&keyword=cool`

however when running the following query:

```
SELECT
hits.page.searchKeyword as Search,
hits.page.pagePath,
hits.page.pageTitle 
FROM
`bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` AS GA,
UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
where
hits.page.searchKeyword IS NOT NULL
```

Page Path and Page Title are `/home` and `Home` for each search.

The definition of `hits.page.searchKeyword` is

`If this was a search results page, this is the keyword entered.`

So looking at the definition I would assume that the returned `Page Path` value would be the url of the search result page no? What do I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

In the view settings, they checked the options "Strip query parameters out of URL" so they don't show up as part of the path. See https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/a54516992w87479473p92320289/admin/view/settings

Comment: query parameters is one thing but page path or page title is another.